# Waiting async method inside sync method without blocking the thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, signalr

I have some code that runs under Unity Game Engine. Parts of that code is also running on the server (IIS 8.0, Azure Cloud). Since Unity only supports a subset of .Net Framework (3.5 or something close to it) it doesn't support at the moment async / await pattern.

Naturally my server is fully built by using async methods. The problem is that Unity code needs to call some of my server methods and it cannot use the await keyword. I need to expose some basic methods for the Unity code so it can call them on the server.

For example I could have the following code:

```
   Public bool Save()
   {
       Task.Run(async() => await PlayerService.SavePlayer());
       return true;
   }
```

This of course runs nicely, but I need to make sure that the method save doesn't return before the save has completed. Now how do I wait for that task to run to the end before it returns to the method Save()? Also do this without blocking the thread? Blocking the method is fine.

Btw. there is a ton of await calls in side the PlayerService.SavePlayer();

Also there is the problem of synchronization context, it seems that when calling the initial call through SignalR it doesn't like if the context changes.

Just to clarify how SignalR is involved here is an example of the pattern:

SignalR gets a message -> This loads a instance of the model (Unity code) from the memory -> The model then thinks it's a good time save its' state and calls the server methods -> Save() method is called -> Save calls async method in playerservices -> this does it's magic -> this returns to save -> Model sees a that save was success and continues to do its' business.

Comment: A thread cannot "wait" without "blocking", since those two are virtually synonyms. Unless you want to busy wait, with `while (!task.IsCompleted) { }`.

Comment: Or maybe you want to wait only in the sense that some code should run only after the task completed? If so, then take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now how do I wait for that task to run to the end before it returns to the method Save()?

In this case, you can `Wait` the `Task` returned by `Task.Run`. This is not an optimal solution (it's a hack), but you can't have an optimal solution unless Unity supports `await`.

> Also do this without blocking the thread?

That's not possible. You're exposing a synchronous method to Unity, and when a synchronous method returns, it's complete. So you *have* to either block the thread or return after starting an asynchronous operation (like your code is already doing).

> Also there is the problem of synchronization context, it seems that when calling the initial call through SignalR it doesn't like if the context changes.

SignalR 1.x had some quirks around `SynchronizationContext`. SignalR 2.0 was just released (and they were supposed to fix those quirks in that release); I'd try upgrading and see if it works better.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the answers, I was secretly hoping that you pick this question up :). Blocking the thread isn't really a option here since that would kill the performance on my servers. Just might need to work my way around the problem so that it doesn't matter if the method return before the task ends.

Comment: Returning early is dangerous; the consequences of returning early are that the action may not actually finish (e.g., your users get a confirmation message that their player was saved, but then it's not actually saved - or only saved partway...). A proper design would be to place the save request in a queue (Azure/MSMQ) and have a separate service process those requests. If you *have* to keep it all in ASP.NET, then you can use a [type on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) to *minimize* the chance of consequences, but they can still happen.

Comment: Queue would be ideal, but it just doesn't have the performance that is needed here. Actually the task in hand is object getting saved to Azure Table, so I think I'm pretty sure the data will get saved. There is also a ton of load balancing and sharding happening before the actual save to the table storage. Also the class doing the saving is preserved in memory until the IIS process ends. And even then it would still use the shutdown timeout time to finish any tasks left undone.

Comment: @NextKalle: The correct way to address the performance issue is to scale out. You [have](http://tinyurl.com/6q7upqq) [no](http://tinyurl.com/lz3xlpc) [guarantees](http://tinyurl.com/adktrz6) for Azure Tables; note that an SLA is not a guarantee of service - it's just a guarantee of payment in case of service disruption. There's no way you can be sure that "the class doing the saving is preserved in memory until the IIS process ends" or that it *can* "use the shutdown timeout time to finish any tasks left undone". Sorry, but I stand by my recommendation of scaling out with a queue.

Comment: I'm already scaling out, big time. No worries there. Queue just doesn't have the performance what tables do. The tables are sharded over multiple accounts for best performance. Of course the shutdown timeout is not used for guaranteed saving method, it's just a precaution if (and when) the instance gets rebooted. And of course there always will be service disruption and when relaying on cloud services that is something that you will just need to live with.

Comment: To be honest... blocking + sleeping that given thread is nowhere of an overkill. If it is a side thread there is no trouble there

Comment: @ArekBal: Unnecessarily blocking a thread is not ideal, but acceptable - *on the client side*. It is certainly *not* what you want to do on the *server* side.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary It depends... as long as it is not something you "per query, per user" do... it is still quite acceptable.

Comment: @ArekBal: Blocking a non-request thread in ASP.NET is always detrimental to server performance and scalability, and has absolutely no benefits. So I'm not sure why you would ever *want* to do it. Feel free to ask your own question if you want more details.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary I just wanted to clear this out that blocking - putting to sleep reasonably - worker thread is "not always detrimental" and has "some benefits" over coroutines, microthreads and such. One such server side case would be thread dedicated to communication with external hardware such as hard drive? If you want to argue for points.. go on and start a question. I am done. Bye. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: @ArekBal: I liked your comment because it made me chuckle. FYI, there is no such thing as a thread dedicated to communicating with a hard drive, unless your application creates one itself. I have a [blog post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) that you may find helpful.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary I disliked your comment because it made me angry(too bad there is no downvoting for comments). FYI, thread dedicated for streaming and decompression from DVD, Hard Drive, MF Internet and compression and streaming over internet are common use cases - for so called "hardware dedicated threads" - amongst the industry :)